# to understanding this line of C++ pointers code

Tags: c++, pointers

I am reading an example code about pointers but I can't understand why the developer write this:

If DD is the class we defined, why is this working?

```
DD *g = 0,h(ARGUMENTS_HERE);
```

but this isn't working (without zero ,)?

```
DD *g = h(ARGUMENTS_HERE);
```

Comment: This question is missing a lot of context. What is `DD`? What is `h`?

Comment: What @goodvibration is trying to tell you is that you need to provide context in the shape of a [mre]. (goodvibration, try typing `[mre]` into a comment like that)

Comment: @goodvibration  DD is my class  that I created. so when I trying to create a pointer in MAIN function I faced the problem what mentioned in question.

Comment: Two different things occur. In the first, you declare a pointer and set it equal to zero and create a forward declaration (prototype) for `h`. In the second you attempt to set `g` to that prototype which has not yet been declared in that scope.

Comment: Get rid of the first example, as it uses the comma operator in an expression.  Split the code into two statements:  `DD * g = 0; g = h(/*...*/);`  Make your code clean and understandable.

Comment: This would be a really interesting question if you provided a [mcve]. Does `h` manipulate `g` in anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the minimal information provided, if I had to guess, I'd say the first line works because g is being defined as a pointer to DD and initialized to be 0, or null. The comma afterwords means that h(with arguments) is defined as a function (with arguments) that returns a DD object (not a pointer to the object, the actual object)

The second line fails because you're trying to initialize g to the return value of the function h. Since we don't know how h is actually defined, I'd guess that it either isn't defined or it is defined but not returning a pointer to DD.

Answer (score -2):

You're declaring two different variables here, one pointer to a DD and one DD object. In the second example you're trying to assign h, which probably doesn't exist, or is an object that you are trying to assign to a pointer.